# Edit variable inside nameless function using extension or by other ways

Tags: javascript, html, greasemonkey, tampermonkey, userscripts

In a website that im using, theres a timeout that logs something in the console and call itself again. Example:

```js
(function(){
  var times = 0;
  var myInterval = function(){
    setTimeout(()=>{
      console.log("my log " + (times++));
      myInterval();
    }, 1000);
  }
  myInterval();
})();
```

By using this nameless function, the site makes it's variables inaccessible thru the console.

The only way i got around it was by going in the "Source" tab and editing the script itself:
[image]

The problem is that this process needs to be done each time that the page is realoaded and i want to make a UserScript or something like that to make this automatically. A little time ago, someone told me that theres a thing that can edit the script before the page loads and i just forgot the name of it.

***RESOLUTION:***

The "thing" that let you edit scripts before they load is **[Resource Override](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/resource-override/pkoacgokdfckfpndoffpifphamojphii)** but i just remenbered after some time, so i didnt use it this time, instead i created my own userscript and this is the result:

With the help of @TheBombSquad i got a way to edit the `setTimeout` native code. With that, i can check the function and stop just the especific one that i want, without breking the rest of the code that depends on the setTimeout.

To make that i need to create my own `setTimeout` function and call it if the function is the one that i want to edit:

```js
(function(){
  var times = 0;
  var myInterval = function(){
    setTimeout(()=>{
      console.log("my log " + (times++));
      myInterval();
    }, 1000);
  }
  myInterval();
  
  var myOtherInterval = function(){
    setTimeout(()=>{
      console.log("my unedited log " + (times++));
      myOtherInterval();
    }, 1000);
  }
  myOtherInterval();
})();


/* Thru my UserScript */


var mySetTimeout = (myFunction, timeOut) => {
    var timer;
    var currentTime = new Date().getTime();
    var runFunction = () => {
      if (new Date().getTime() >= currentTime + timeOut) {
        clearInterval(timer);
        myFunction();
      }
    }
    timer = setInterval(runFunction, 100);
}

setTimeout = function(myFunction, timeOut){
    var boole = (myFunction + "").includes('console.log("my log "');
    if(!boole){ /* if its not the function that i need */
        mySetTimeout(myFunction, timeOut);
    } else {
        var myInterval = function(){
          mySetTimeout(()=>{
            console.log("My edited log YEY!");
            myInterval();
          }, timeOut); 
        }
        myInterval();
    }
};
```

Thanks to everyone!

Comment: Perhaps "long time ago" was when Firefox was a thing...we could use [beforescriptexecute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/beforescriptexecute_event) event

Comment: theres no way to edit the variables inside this function?

Comment: there is.. think about hijacking the globals that the function uses ;3

Comment: i assume u trying to mess with `times` right?

Comment: @vanowm - not sure how beforescriptexecute would help this particular problem, at least not without an web extension that loads a handler for the event before the page loads - and if you're going to use an web extension, you can pretty much change the code without such an event

Comment: @TheBombSquad i dont know what is `times` lol

Comment: @bravo, I've used that method in greasemonkey userscript to remove part of the scripts or block scripts before it was executed.

Comment: @vanowm - yes, of course - are you one of the 6 people still using Firefox, now we need to find the other 4

Comment: @LuísHNrique `times` as in the example variable u have in your snippet

Comment: @TheBombSquad kinda this, actually i just want to edit the function, if its possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All I can do is run the function when I want to from remodeling the `setTimeout` global function

```js
const s=setTimeout; let c=0
setTimeout=function(fn){
  if(!c){window.addToTimes=fn}
}

;(function(){
  var times = 0;
  var myInterval = function(){
    setTimeout(()=>{
      console.log("my log " + (times++));
      myInterval();
    }, 1000);
  }
  myInterval();
})();

//example usage(it just runs the embedded function)
addToTimes(); addToTimes()
```

Comment: this stoped the interval but kinda broke the rest of the code, what i want i a way to edit the script before loading the page

Comment: Becouse others things on the code beyond this functions depends on the setTimeout

Comment: Is ther a way to execute the function inside the setTimeout remodeling without making a self loop? i just tryed: `setTimeout=function(fn){if(!c){fn()}}` but it just loops the log infinitelly

Comment: I figurated it out, by creating my own setTimeout i can edit the function and and runing it thru my setTimeout, THX!